# Dbeaver to SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

I need to connect to SQL Server using the DBeaver credentials. Which drivers do I need to install and how I can proceed? I want to take the data from one of the database of DBeaver to a SQL table.

Answer (score 1):

In DBeaver, create a SQL Server connection, go to the "Driver Properties". If you haven't yet downloaded the driver, DBeaver will prompt you if you want to download the driver.